# React.js useEffect and dependency array, using destructuring useState

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, destructuring

## React.js useEffect and  dependency array

A tutorial code, invoke a state change function, to force a render
( adding a comma using array destructuring).

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useAnyKeyToRender = () => {

    const [ , forceRender ] = useState();

    useEffect( () => {
        window.addEventListener( "keydown", forceRender );
        return () => window.removeEventListener( "keydown", forceRender );
    }, [] );

};

export default function App() {

    useAnyKeyToRender();

    useEffect( () => {
        console.log( "fresh render" );
    } );

    return <h1>Open the console</h1>;
}
```

In this hook we don’t care about the state value. We only want the state function: forceRender.

I understand how arrays destructuring works

```js
const [fruit, setFruit] = useState('banana');
```

**is equivalent to**

```js
var fruitStateVariable = useState('banana'); // Returns a pair
var fruit = fruitStateVariable[0]; // First item in a pair
var setFruit = fruitStateVariable[1]; // Second item in a pair
```

I don't understand how this code works

```js
 const [ , forceRender ] = useState();
```

Why the first array element is blank (ignored), and why forceRender is the second element.

Why **setForceRender** is not used ?

How is invoked forceRender ?

I understood the goal of this hook, but no the dependency array trick.

If i do: console.log(forceRender), appears:

```js
  ƒ bound dispatchAction() {}
<constructor>: "Function"
name: "Function"
```

I don't understand how this hook works, and how forceRender function mechanism.
It seems simples but i'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't seem to find any information online, so I am going to give you what I think is happening. I am not an expert, just someone who wants to provide his perspective. If anyone wants to correct me, please do!

---

### With that out of the way:

Let's look at this line of code:

```js
// This isn't really useful but for the sake of this explanation
const [, setName] = useState("John")
```

The return statement of `useState` would look something like this:

```
function useState(initialState) {
    // other code here
    return [state, setState]
}
```

`setState` is at index `1`, and we are requesting that index `1` is assigned to `setName`, and ignore index `0`. This is what I believe is happening. This may be incorrect or maybe not even known due to it not being documented well (I couldn't even find any info on MDN!), but this is what I think is happening.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers! It seems the first element in the array is blank const [ , forceRender ],  the state value is ignored, what is wanted is  the state function: forceRender.  But it's not yet very clear how it exactly works.

Comment: The difficulty here is setName is not used but name : const [, name] = useState("John"), like the const [ , forceRender ] = useState();

Comment: The legitimate construction is const [fruit, setFruit] = useState('banana');

Comment: `useState` returns an array with two elements (the value, and the setter.  The `const [value, setValue] = useState` syntax is simply setting `value` to the first and `setValue` to the second.  `value`and `setValue` are just variable names so you can call them whatever you like.  In your case, the `value` is not used so `const [ , forceRender ]` is simply throwing away the value and storing the setter function into `forceRender`.

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment. I guessed useState was related to getter and setValue is related to setter. Using the destructuring array method could be confusing in the beginning.